# Excel 2007 Copy range values and paste to another range (Same Sheet) first empty row

Tags: excel, vba

Total Newbie here. Need help making this simple code work. Every time I run the macro I need it to find the next open row in the target row and paste. Obviously the first time I run, it work but the next time it pastes it on top of the previous paste. The number of rows I need it to paste will vary, so it needs to check the space then paste what it's copying each time I run the code.

```
Sub Save()
Range("A19:I100").Copy Destination:=Range("N5:V1000")
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use next code:

```
Sub Save()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A19:I100").Copy Destination:=Range("N" & lastrow + 1)
End Sub
```